# FDR-persistent: The ID survives factory reset

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I need a device identifier that persists after the app is uninstalled and reinstalled. I know that UUID class provides an identifier with the method

String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

but Android guideline is unclear about its scope and persistence. In next paragraph it says:

Resettability and persistence

Resettability and persistence define the lifespan of the identifier and explain how it can be reset. Common reset triggers include: in-app resets, resets via System Settings, resets on launch, and resets on installation. Android identifiers can have varying lifespans, but the lifespan is usually related to how the ID is reset:

Session-only: A new ID is used every time the user restarts the app.
Install-reset: A new ID is used every time user uninstalls and reinstalls the app.
FDR-reset: A new ID is used every time the user factory-resets the device.
FDR-persistent: The ID survives factory reset.
Resettability gives users the ability to create a new ID that is disassociated from any existing profile information. The longer, and more reliably, an identifier persists, such as one that persists across factory resets, the greater the risk that the user may be subjected to long-term tracking. If the identifier is reset upon app reinstall, this reduces the persistence and provides a means for the ID to be reset, even if there is no explicit user control to reset it from within the app or System Settings.

Please tell me how can I use FDR-persistent: The ID survives factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

`String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();` will give you a different "number" each time you run it. That is random generated every time.

As far as I know, if you want a FDR-persistent number it has to be either serial number or IMEI (in case the device has as SIM card slot). You could also use MAC address, though this is pretty public.